# React-select - resolve a promise according to state value

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-select

I am currently using React-select async.

My options are returned based on the states return from its parent, which is from an async process.
Found that the options in select box keeps empty because my `options` from parent is not returned yet.

Except moving in the async process from parent into this `MultiDropdownSelectBox` component, is there any way to resolve the promise when I get the options (which is not empty array) from its parent? Like keep checking on the options and resolve it when it is not empty? or using `useEffect`?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';

const MultiDropdownSelectBox = ({options}) => {

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const promiseOptions = inputValue =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(options);
    }, 1000);
  });

  return (
    <AsyncSelect
      isMulti
      cacheOptions
      defaultOptions
      loadOptions={promiseOptions}
    />
  );
}
```

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing so. Wouldn't it be better, instead of give the options array, just pass the loadOptions (The promise) as a prop from the parent to MultiDropdownSelectBox?

Comment: @N.Dias Inspired! I will try to do so, thanks!